# Which encoding should I choose when saving files in Kile?

Tags: unicode, editors, input-encodings, kile, utf8

I noticed that Kile appears to have changed the default encoding for files to x-UTF_8j. It has also developed a bewildering list of encoding options in the file saving dialogue. (So this is probably not specific to Kile.)

I usually use UTF-8. There are now two of those. There are two of a bunch of other options.

What is x-UTF_8j and is there some reason Kile has switched to it?

The vast majority of the enormous number of encoding options mean absolutely nothing to me. What does (either of the) 037 mean, for example?

The Tools > Encoding menu still seems to offer the same options, so it is only the file dialogue which appears to have proliferated these less-than-transparent options.

Comment: That is imho simply an alias for utf8, see eg https://icu4c-demos.unicode.org/icu-bin/convexp?s=IANA&s=MIME&s=ALL

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah! Thank-you. Do you want to make that an answer? (I'd like to know that link is somewhere I can find it!) I'm still bemused by the purely numerical options ('037' and so on) but, practically speaking, that's much less important. (I also don't find the enormous list helpful, but that's a UI question.)